# How can I get work items that have a related test in Azure DevOps (VSTS)?

Tags: azure, testing, azure-devops, devops, azure-boards

I really love the query function to find work items but I cannot figure out how to query for work items that are linked to tests. Is there any column that might help me? Or any other way to get a list of work items that are linked to tests and one for the ones that aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Work items and direct links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#use-direct-links-to-view-dependencies)**. User stories without test cases:

[image]